# Abort running MSTest unit tests in VisualStudio 2012

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, mstest

How do I stop a running MSTest unit test in VisualStudio 2012?

This seems silly, but I can't seem to find a way. I accidentally wrote a unit test that gets stuck at some point and waits forever.

Comment: there should be a Cancel/Cancel all button in the TestExplorer window

Comment: lol, d'uh.. found it. I guess it's time for a break. ;) yeah, I'm new to VS2012.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there ***IS*** a Cancel/Cancel all button in the TestExplorer window. 
(There is a new row of buttons between the search bar and the list of tests, which apparently is easily overlooked.)

Thanks Tyler!

Comment: It was hard to find for me, too. :-)